# Iteration through dataframe creating histograms

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

My data comes from a RNA_seq analysis. I am trying to depict the CPM and frequency just put some context on frequency of zeros (CPM) of the different genes

I provide some small piece of dataset called dat. From this dataset I would like to follow doing something like this.

```
# Create an empty list to store ggplot objects
histogram_plots <- list()

# Iterate through the elements
for (element in goi) {
  # Filter data for the specific element
  element_data <- dat[dat$Gene == element, ]
  
  # Create a ggplot histogram for the element
  plot <- ggplot(element_data, aes(x = CPM, y = after_stat(Frequency / sum(Frequency)))) +
    geom_histogram(fill = "cornflowerblue", color = "white", binwidth = 5) +
    labs(title = paste("Frequency Distribution of", element),
         y = "Percent",
         x = "CPM") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
    theme_minimal()
  
  # Add the ggplot object to the list
  histogram_plots[[element]] <- plot
  
  # Save the ggplot object as an image file (adjust the filename and format accordingly)
  ggsave(paste0("histogram_", gsub("-", "_", element), ".png"), plot, width = 8, height = 6)
}
```

Error in `geom_histogram()`:
! Problem while mapping stat to aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error:
! objeto 'Frequency' no encontrado
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Throws the error that Frequency is not found, but is clearly there. I am not sure if this is related with NSE and this staff

The df

```
dat <- structure(list(Gene = c("hsa-miR-139-5p", "hsa-miR-139-5p", "hsa-miR-139-5p", 
"hsa-miR-139-5p", "hsa-miR-139-5p", "hsa-miR-139-5p", "hsa-miR-139-5p", 
"hsa-miR-139-5p", "hsa-miR-139-5p", "hsa-miR-139-5p", "hsa-miR-139-5p", 
"hsa-miR-139-5p", "hsa-miR-139-5p", "hsa-miR-139-5p", "hsa-miR-139-5p", 
"hsa-miR-139-5p", "hsa-miR-139-5p", "hsa-miR-139-5p", "hsa-miR-139-5p", 
"hsa-miR-139-5p", "hsa-miR-144-3p", "hsa-miR-144-3p", "hsa-miR-144-3p", 
"hsa-miR-144-3p", "hsa-miR-144-3p", "hsa-miR-144-3p", "hsa-miR-144-3p", 
"hsa-miR-144-3p", "hsa-miR-144-3p", "hsa-miR-144-3p", "hsa-miR-144-3p", 
"hsa-miR-144-3p", "hsa-miR-144-3p", "hsa-miR-144-3p", "hsa-miR-144-3p", 
"hsa-miR-144-3p", "hsa-miR-144-3p", "hsa-miR-144-3p", "hsa-miR-144-3p", 
"hsa-miR-144-3p", "hsa-miR-15a-5p", "hsa-miR-15a-5p", "hsa-miR-15a-5p", 
"hsa-miR-15a-5p", "hsa-miR-15a-5p", "hsa-miR-15a-5p", "hsa-miR-15a-5p", 
"hsa-miR-15a-5p", "hsa-miR-15a-5p", "hsa-miR-15a-5p", "hsa-miR-15a-5p", 
"hsa-miR-15a-5p", "hsa-miR-15a-5p", "hsa-miR-15a-5p", "hsa-miR-15a-5p", 
"hsa-miR-15a-5p", "hsa-miR-15a-5p", "hsa-miR-15a-5p", "hsa-miR-15a-5p", 
"hsa-miR-15a-5p", "hsa-miR-28-3p", "hsa-miR-28-3p", "hsa-miR-28-3p", 
"hsa-miR-28-3p", "hsa-miR-28-3p", "hsa-miR-28-3p", "hsa-miR-28-3p", 
"hsa-miR-28-3p", "hsa-miR-28-3p", "hsa-miR-28-3p", "hsa-miR-28-3p", 
"hsa-miR-28-3p", "hsa-miR-28-3p", "hsa-miR-28-3p", "hsa-miR-28-3p", 
"hsa-miR-28-3p", "hsa-miR-28-3p", "hsa-miR-28-3p", "hsa-miR-28-3p", 
"hsa-miR-28-3p", "hsa-miR-92a-3p", "hsa-miR-92a-3p", "hsa-miR-92a-3p", 
"hsa-miR-92a-3p", "hsa-miR-92a-3p", "hsa-miR-92a-3p", "hsa-miR-92a-3p", 
"hsa-miR-92a-3p", "hsa-miR-92a-3p", "hsa-miR-92a-3p", "hsa-miR-92a-3p", 
"hsa-miR-92a-3p", "hsa-miR-92a-3p", "hsa-miR-92a-3p", "hsa-miR-92a-3p", 
"hsa-miR-92a-3p", "hsa-miR-92a-3p", "hsa-miR-92a-3p", "hsa-miR-92a-3p", 
"hsa-miR-92a-3p"), CPM = c(140, 840, 820, 1740, 100, 460, 40, 
940, 760, 340, 620, 680, 380, 1360, 660, 1440, 180, 360, 720, 
1100, 2000, 0, 4300, 8600, 1200, 9100, 3100, 7300, 5100, 4100, 
3200, 9400, 6600, 2600, 2200, 7800, 2400, 10100, 6900, 8500, 
2600, 450, 2800, 2750, 0, 1400, 1550, 650, 1800, 1300, 3200, 
1750, 2300, 2500, 300, 8050, 600, 1950, 3150, 750, 140, 580, 
380, 500, 570, 740, 30, 490, 410, 250, 340, 540, 550, 260, 350, 
470, 680, 100, 180, 530, 3700, 100, 2900, 2100, 2800, 1700, 6900, 
2200, 2600, 2150, 1300, 300, 350, 3200, 1500, 1650, 2700, 2550, 
1850, 3600), Frequency = c(7, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 7, 2, 1, 
5, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 3, 2, 3, 21, 8, 1, 5, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 
1, 2, 4, 2, 7, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 30, 7, 2, 6, 5, 6, 1, 4, 
3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 8, 1, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 
1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 9, 1, 
5, 6, 1, 1, 4, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

UPDATE: [image]

Comment: You're using after_stat. You don't have the original Frequency in a histogram, you have among other things _count_. What do you actually want to plot? CPM on the x-axis and what exactly on the y-axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when using `after_stat` you no longer have access to your raw data. Instead, the `stat` is transforming your raw data, e.g. a `geom_histogram` or `stat="bin"` will bin your data according to the variable mapped on `x` and computes the counts for each bin. These counts are then stored in a column named `count`. `after_stat()` allows to work with the transformed data or the data after the stat has been applied. But inside `after_stat` you can only access the columns of the transformed data, e.g. you could do `after_stat(count / sum(count))`.

However, overall your code does not make that much sense to me. As your data already includes the `Frequency` of your genes I would guess that you simply want a bar chart of these frequencies, which could be easily achieved using a `geom_col`. Additionally, note that when creating `ggplot`s in a loop it is best to use `lapply` to avoid any issues due to lazy evaluation:

```r
library(ggplot2)

goi <- unique(dat$Gene)
names(goi) <- goi

# Iterate through the elements
histogram_plots <- lapply(goi, \(element) {
  # Filter data for the specific element
  element_data <- dat[dat$Gene == element, ]

  # Create a ggplot histogram for the element
  plot <- ggplot(element_data, aes(x = CPM, y = Frequency / sum(Frequency))) +
    geom_col(fill = "cornflowerblue", color = "white") +
    labs(
      title = paste("Frequency Distribution of", element),
      y = "Percent",
      x = "CPM"
    ) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
    theme_minimal()

  # Save the ggplot object as an image file (adjust the filename and format accordingly)
  # ggsave(paste0("histogram_", gsub("-", "_", element), ".png"), plot, width = 8, height = 6)

  plot
})

histogram_plots[1:2]
#> $`hsa-miR-139-5p`
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> $`hsa-miR-144-3p`
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly but when saving the plots using the ggsave line, it changes the bottom colour and bars

Comment: Hi Javier, could you clarify what you mean by *changes the bottom colour and bars*?